# One to Many Conditional Association with Polymorphic table: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, polymorphic-associations

I've a polymorphic address table,

```
   create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.integer :address_type, default: 0, null: false
      t.string :addressable_type
      t.integer :addressable_id
      t.belongs_to :city
      t.belongs_to :state
      t.belongs_to :country
      t.string :address_line_1
      t.string :address_line_2
      t.string :address_line_3
      t.integer :pin_code, limit: 6
      t.datetime :deleted_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

The idea to keep `address_type` to assign local, permanent address as below:

```
enum address_type: {default: 0, local: 1, permanent: 2, residential: 3, office: 4}
```

The problem is, how do I define association to define:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :local_address 
end
```

I tried quite a few options such as:

```
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
  has_one :present_address, -> { where address_type: :local }, through: :addresses, source: :addressable
  has_one :present_address, -> { addresses.where(address_type: :local) }
```

OR

```
has_one :present_address, through: :addresses, conditions: { address_type: :local }, source: :addressable
has_one :permanent_address, through: :addresses, conditions: { address_type: :permanent }, source: :addressable
```

But to no avail. How should we define such association?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Still new to Rails so correct me if I'm mistaken or wrong. Hope I understood your requirement correctly.

I think, polymorphic associations are useful when you want a model to have a belongs_to association with more than one model at a time. In your case, it seems you are associating the Address model with only one model, that is the User model.

Let's consider the Address model without polymorphic association, with the following fields.
user_id, address_type, city, state, country, address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3, pin_code, deleted_at

Notice the user_id field in order to associate an address with a user. This will need your Address model to include

```
belongs_to :user
```

Now you can have a User model as below:

```
has_many :addresses
has_one :local_address, -> { where address_type: "local" }, class_name: "Address"
```

Add similar lines of code for permanent_address, residential_address etc.

In this case, the possible values of address_type field in Address model would be "local", "permanent", "residential", "office" etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have `address` table associated with other tables as well. But there I have one to one association(default address) without any problem. But user can have multiple address, so I pasted `User` table snippet. 
`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "local_address" or :local_address in model Address. Try 'has_many :local_address, :through => :addresses, :source => <name>'. Is it one of versions, addressable, city, state, or country?
from activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:850:in `check_validity!'`

Comment: Tried all these options, but did not work. Also, for `:through` we need an intermediate table. So I'm sure I'm missing anything here.
One work around is to remove `polymorphism` and do it as a simple association.

Comment: I think I got it. Replace 

`has_one :permanent_address, through: :addresses, conditions: { address_type: :permanent }, source: :addressable` 

with 

`has_one :permanent_address, -> { where address_type: 2 }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address"`

Comment: It didn't work earlier. But somehow, today it worked. Thanks.